# How do I convert a CMYK tif with unknown profile to png (RBG)?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I am trying to convert a tiff CMYK image to PNG and cannot find out the ICC profile, which leads to wrong colors in the converted PNG.

I tried the following to determine the profile:

```sh
$ identify -format "%[profile:icc]" test.tif
```

With no result.

And, the following, with no usable result:

```sh
$ identify -verbose test.tiff |grep -i profile
    crs:CameraProfile: Adobe Standard
    crs:CameraProfileDigest: 3DA8CE4A626CE36A1D0C55BF157793C9
    crs:LensProfileEnable: 0
    crs:LensProfileSetup: LensDefaults
  Profiles:
    Profile-8bim: 8730 bytes
    Profile-tiff:37724: 3132408 bytes
    Profile-xmp: 30533 bytes
```

After that I downloaded Adobe's profiles and tried each of them, but not a single one did work. This is how I tried to apply the profiles:

```sh
convert -profile CMYKProfiles.icc -profile AppleRGB.icc -colorspace rgb test.tif test.png
```

That works, but only if I know the profile and supply the right profile. In my case that doesn't work.

Is the image just broken or is there a way to convert it preserving its colors?

Comment: Post your tif file. Note that in your convert command, you should read the input before applying profiles. More importantly, do not combine -profile with -colorspace. Use only profiles or -colorspace, not both. Perhaps you tif file has no CMYK profile, but is in CMYK colorspace. You can check for profiles using EXIFTOOL. See https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/

Comment: Thanks for your Reply.   
I was not aware that the image could just have no profile. I also was not aware that `-colorspace` and `-profile` are mutually exclusive.    
Here's the image: [test.tif.zip](http://www.google.com/https://lost-illusions.de/test.tif.zip).

Comment: `@Christopher` Your link to test.tif.zip does not work for me. I get a 404 error.

Comment: @fmw42 Because I'm a nitwit and I mixed two links. This is the right one: https://lost-illusions.de/test.tif.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file has 4 layers or pages. The one you want seems to be the first layer/page. Each is CMYK with no color profile. Without profiles, it is possible that each display device might show the image differently depending upon what default profile is used, if any.

But with Imagemagick, I get pretty close using USWebCoatedSwop.icc and sRGB.icc profiles as follows

```
convert -quiet test.tif[0] -profile /Users/fred/images/profiles/USWebCoatedSwop.icc -profile /Users/fred/images/profiles/sRGB.icc test.png
```

[test.png](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/tif_proc/test.png)

Comment: that did the track, thanks a lot. Does that mean that the colors are trial and error if no color profile is supplied?

Comment: Yes, likely. As I mentioned, I believe under that condition, different viewers *may* display the image differently, depending whether and what profile they may apply.

Comment: I see. Thanks again, @fmw42. Your help is much appreciated!